# Why am I losing data when navigating between pages? (wp8)

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8, sdk

Okay so lets say I got 2 pages.
The first one contains a textbox and a button, the second one contain a listbox.

It's simple, if you write something in that textbox and click that button, the info will be added to the listbox.

Code in the first page

```
dim textitem as string = ""
NavigationService.Navigate(New Uri("/Page1.xaml?text=" & textitem,  UriKind.Relative))
```

Code in the second page

```
dim newitem as string = ""
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    MyBase.OnNavigatedTo(e)
    If NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("text", newitem) Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(newitem)
    End If
End Sub
```

Now everything works just fine and the item gets added.
The Problem is that when I go back to the first page without transmitting any data and then go back to the second page without transmitting any data the item disappears and the second page goes back the way it was in the first place.

Why is this happening? should I be doing something else? or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks a lot in advance.

(Same thing is happening when I am using a normal browser, if I am browsing something on my First page and then I decide to go to the second page and then go back to the first page the webbrowser is blank.)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you implement some kind of page caching, **for each navigate a new page instance is created** - so your data is not preserved. You may want to put breakpoints in the page constructor to test that.

The page provides a `State` dictionary, where you can store all data that needs to be restored.

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedFrom(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    State("MyPageState") = allState
End Sub


Protected Overrides Sub OnNavigatedTo(ByVal e As System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs)
    allState = CType(State("MyPageState"),MyStateObject)
End Sub
```

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more info about page state.

Comment: I see, Thanks a lot, I will check it out and see how it goes.

Comment: Okay I read everything and I tried it out and it worked on some simple project. Anyways, when I came back to my question; when it comes webbrowsers how is the binding suppose to work? What I actually mean is that when it comes to textboxes you can go for Text but what is it with when it comes to webbrowsers?

Comment: Are you using the webbrowser control? You should open a second question for that, I think it's a different issue.

Comment: It's actually kind of the same, since it's also about preserving the state of the browser, anyways, I think the only way is to focus on the source even though I am not sure about it. I will give it a try.

Comment: And I just realized that what you wrote and the article you shared with me are 2 different things :P